# selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Selenium script in Python. It works, but lately has been crashing sporadically with a timeout error. I tried to follow some of the solutions online. Here's the chrome options:

```
#set driver options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1420,1080')
chrome_options.headless = True
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
chrome_options.binary_location='/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
chrome_driver_binary = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

And it runs through maybe 100 or 200 URLs before crashing with this error:

```
      File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 299.892
  (Session info: headless chrome=91.0.4472.114)
```

The error is happening on the `driver.get()` line of Python code.

Chromedriver version is 91.0.4472.101 and Google Chrome version is 91.0.4472.114.

What else can I try?

Comment: Can you try updating Browser and driver both  ?

Comment: yes i've updated both.

Comment: how about setting options.setPageLoadStrategy(NONE) ?  Is this a valid strategy?